# How to select whole environment in TeXstudio

Tags: texstudio

> When I was a Windows user (a long time ago), I remember that it was
>   possible to select the whole environment in WinEdt just by double
>   clicking the `\begin` command.
>
> Is it possible to do this in TeXstudio? How do we select an
>   environment?
>
> ---
>
> **Edit** I tried the suggestions below with no progress. I am posting an image showing what happens when I press the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>
>   and **(after released the 3 keys)** I pressed the key `i` or `I`.
>   First, with the cursor at the right, that is, `\begin{equation}|`
>   (note the yellow color). Second, after <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>, note the
>   `equation` in blue color. Then, I pressed only the key `i` (I tried
>   also only `I`).

[image]

Comment: I have been using TeXstudio for a while now and I can say that it does not have this capability. Although it would be very helpful if TeXStudio (and TeXmaker) would have this capability.

Comment: Crosspost in the [TeXstudio forum](https://sourceforge.net/projects/texstudio/forums/forum/907840/topic/6016338/index/page/1).

Comment: I posted it there.

Comment: We'd like to keep answers separate from questions, so you should write a separate answer instead of editing your answer into the question. Self-answers are perfectly admissible, and a well-written answer may earn you additional reputation.

Comment: @Sigur Could you please follow up on Qrr..’s suggestion?

Comment: As the answer of you. I think you should update or reinstall texstudio. Then it will work. However, I think there should be some better answer. Any body?

Comment: @Hamid, this question is very old. Now I'm using the latest version of txs.

Comment: Does it work the same way? or you use another method? A better (shorter) shortcut may  exist. Do you know any?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As benibela from the TeXstudio development group answered:

> The cursor has to be placed directly at the border of the 
>   parenthesis/environment. I.e. if `|` marks the cursor, it has to be either there: `|\begin{example}` or there: `\begin{example}|` (where it is highlighted)

So, if you have the following code snippet

```
\begin{itemize}
  \begin{enumerate}
    inner content
  \end{enumerate}
\end{itemize}
```

and place the cursor like this (notice the yellow highlighting):
[image: cursor before \begin]
you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>, <kbd>I</kbd> (for **P**arenthesis/**I**nner) to get

[image: inner selection]
or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>, <kbd>O</kbd> (for **P**arenthesis/**O**uter) to get

[image]

---

Also available is:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>, <kbd>J</kbd> to **j**ump to the corresponding `begin`/`{` or `end`/`}`,
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>, <kbd>M</kbd> to find a **m**ismatching brace.

Comment: Thanks for attention. But when I press `Ctrl+Shift+P,{O/J/M}` nothing happens. But when I press `Ctrl+Shift+P,I` a new `\item` is inserted, at the cursor position, even outside the environment. The selection does not work here. I'm using `TeXstudio 2.4 (SVN 3256:3257)`.

Comment: @Sigur You must not press Ctrl+Shift when pressing the second key.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem solved!!**

I found what is wrong with my TeXstudio. When I was pressing `ctrl+shift+P` I could see something blinking on the status bar. I noticed that this sequence of keys was setting the open file as master file.

So, I checked the shortcuts and I discovered the same shortcut used for two functions. After removing this, **everything is working now!!**

Thanks for attention and please close the topic. Regards.